What is currently the best options for a non sequence-parallel RNN model?
It's well known that sequence-parallel models (like Transformer, Mamba, RWKV etc.) are by design unable to efficiently solve inherently sequential problems and even much simpler state tracking tasks (for some proofs see "The Illusion of State in State-Space Models"). Hence the question, what is currently the best/fastest non sequence-parallel model which is able to solve these types of problems? sLSTM (from the new xLSTM paper) seems promising for these.
